# Permute a tensorflow Tensor

Tags: tensorflow

How do I permute a particular dimension of my tf tensor in the following patter:
e.g. [0,1,2,3,4] --> [1,2,3,4,0]?

More generally, how do I do a rotation by n positions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# 't' is [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
tf.roll(t, shift=-1, axis=0) ==> [1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
```